# Vuejs update a list in reactive manner

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I've two components
1. `viewAndUpdateDish.vue`
2. `updateDish.vue`

In `viewAndUpdateDish`,

1. user pick a restaurant from the drop down
2. dishes of that particular restaurant will filter out and loaded to the table.

[image]

3. then the user hit the update button on a dish and go to `updateDish.vue` component and update the dish.
4. then after he update the dish user is redirected to the `viewAndUpdateDish`

When the user redirected to the `viewAndUpdateDish` that previously selected restaurant should be selected and dishes should loaded. This is my use case.

What I did so far is,

1. create a variable called pickedRestaurantId in vuex store and when user select a restaurant I updated that Id.
2. And in the updateDish component at the end of the update function, I emit a event like this, `this.$root.$emit("clickedUpdate");`
3. And then in the viewAndUpdateDish compoent I did

   ```
   mounted() {
    this.$root.$on("clickedSomething", () => {
    this.loadDishes(this.pickedResViewAndUpdateDish);
   });
   },
   ```

But this doesn't seems work!
How do I achieve this using vuejs?
Hope my question is clear to you.

Comment: You probably need a global place where you put your dish data and  use it at multiple places - Are you using `vuex`? If not I recommend to manage your store - https://vuex.vuejs.org/

Comment: I think you have to use global vuex & you have to write a function in "computed". Whenever any computed dependecny variable component will automatically rerendered.

Comment: If you want to use component in previous state only we have to use <keep-alive> for the component

Comment: @SatyamPathak I've already use vuex to keep the variable pickedRestaurantId

Comment: Please go through computed & keep alive ..I think with these concepts whatever u need can be acheived..

Comment: @PALLAMOLLASAI Thanks I'll go through it and see.

Comment: If your template is using a reactive list (data, prop, computed), you do not need to use vuex or rely on events.  Post your template line that loops the items. If you do use vuex, to can just refer tho the list in you template.  `$store.state.list`.

Comment: Did your problem solved through computed properties & keep alive?

Answer (score 0):

On your "viewAndUpdateDish" component after your update logic you can do the following: 
`this.$emit('clickedUpdate',yourResturantId);`

then on your parent component make sure you are listening to the "clickedUpdate" event:

`<update-dish @clickedUpdate="loadDishes($event)"></update-dish>` .